# socket.handshake.session.keyname shows undefined

Tags: sockets, session, express-session

I'm making a multiplayer game. below is the flow of the process when i get an error:

(1) After logging in the username is getting stored in session:

```
socket.on('login', function(username) 
    {
        socket.handshake.session.username = username;
        socket.handshake.session.save();
        var afterLogin = '/groups';
        socket.emit('afterLogin', afterLogin);
    });
```

(2) User get redirect to another page and complete the game, after completing the game user send score and room id to the server:

```
var submitScore = { score: hit, room: 'gryffindor'};
socket.emit('submitScore', submitScore);
```

(3) Server get the score and room-id and iterate through all the client and decide the max score, get the username from the session, and send the winner name and score to all user:

```
socket.on('submitScore', function(submitScore)
    {
        var room = submitScore.room;
        var score = submitScore.score;
        if (room == "gryffindor") 
        {
            gryfScoreArray[socket.handshake.session.username] = score;
            checkGryfUser --;
            if (checkGryfUser == 0)
            {
                var max = 0;
                var winnerName;
                for(var index in gryfScoreArray) 
                {
                    if (gryfScoreArray[index] > max) 
                    {
                        max = gryfScoreArray[index];
                        winnerName = index;;
                    }
                }
                // console.log(socket.id);
                var winner = {username: winnerName, maxScore: max}
                io.in(room).emit('gryfWinner', winner); 
                // console.log(winner.username);
                // console.log(winner.maxScore);
            }
        }
```

So, the problem is `socket.handshake.session.username` giving undefined in point point **(3)**

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm trying to get simple session handling done with `express-socket.io-session`, but keep loosing the session on browser refresh...

Comment: Hey @Gonnagle, It's been more than 2 years since I worked on the socket.io. I don't exactly remember the solution but somehow I did manage to solve the problem. You can find the solution in my repo: 

https://github.com/Dhara159/winbyhit

Comment: This is the exact file where I have written the socket code: https://github.com/Dhara159/winbyhit/blob/master/index.js